# How can i add meeting url (session url) in generated ics file? which will appear on join button as joining link(custom event link) on teams calendar?

Tags: javascript, outlook, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, icalendar

Right now i have added session link in description properties. I want that session link should display on join link in outlook and teams calendar. Has anybody run into the same situation?
Please let me know if i can achieve this or not ?

let descriptionLink = `<div> <div> ${this.state.eventDescription}</div> <a href=${this.state.sessionLink}>Join Session</a> </div>`;
let url = [
"BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
"VERSION:2.0",
"BEGIN:VEVENT",
"DTSTART:" + this.formatDate(this.state.startTime),
"DTEND:" + this.formatDate(this.state.endTime),
"SUMMARY:" + this.state.eventTitle,
"LOCATION:" + this.state.location,
"X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:" + descriptionLink,
"BEGIN:VALARM",
"TRIGGER:-PT15M",
"REPEAT:1",
"DURATION:PT15M",
"ACTION:DISPLAY",
"DESCRIPTION:Reminder",
"END:VALARM",
"END:VEVENT",
"END:VCALENDAR"
].join("\n");

```
let blob = new Blob([url], { type: 'text/calendar;charset=utf-8' });
if (/msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
  // Open/Save link in IE and Edge
  let tt: any = window.navigator;
  tt.msSaveBlob(blob, 'download.ics');
} else {
  // Open/Save link in Modern Browsers
  window.open(encodeURI("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + url));
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this? Please share the sample you are referring to or any repro steps.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Actually i want to create ics file from SharePoint event list using JavaScript/react. But I want to add personal session/event URL in ics file which URL showcase  as join option in Microsoft teams calendar event. Here is the reference code I have tried https://marclloyd.co.uk/javascript/creating-an-add-to-calendar-link-in-react/.
I couldn't find any parameter/properties in which i can bind my session/event URL